# Xamarin.Uitest My query is working fine on calabash-android console but it is not working on my Xamarin code Visual studio (Android)

Tags: automated-tests, android-uiautomator, xamarin.uitest

So I have a text that I want to get from a popup

When I run on calabash-android the following query :

```
query("* id:'my_object_id', text")[0]
```

Then I am getting the text that I want to check

But If i run on my code Xamarin :

```
app.Query(c => c.Id("my_object_id")).Length; ==> I am getting 0

app.Query(c => c.Id("my_object_id"))[0].Text; ==> Null
```

I tried all other ways :

```
app.Query(c => c.Marked("my_object_id"))[0].Text; ==> Null

app.Query(c => c.Class("TextView").Descendant().Id("my_object_id")).FirstOrDefault().Text; ==> Null
```

I finaly found a way to fix it, but I don't really like the solution :

```
app.Query(c => c.Property("text").Contains("a small part of the text that I want to check")).Length; ==> I got 1

app.Query(c => c.Property("text").Contains("a small part of the text that I want to check"))[0].Text; ==> I am getting the full text that i want to check
```

Is there any explanation for this "wierd" behavior ?

Comment: What version of Xamarin.UITest & NUnit are you using?

Comment: Xamarin.Uitest : 2.0.0 and I try it also with 2.0.3
NUnit : 2.6.4

Comment: The latest version of UITest is 2.0.8, so you might try that to see if it makes a difference. Otherwise it sounds like it could be a bug, but I'm not 100% sure.